# Accessing Terms in Folder using SharePoint Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I created a content type of type folder and I added two taxonomy fields, as you can see.
[image]

I'm trying to access the fields *Tag* and *Grupo de produtos*, I already tried this code below:

```
https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Negocio/OfertaParticulares/_api/web/folders('Dinamico')/folders
```

[image]

But is not showing the terms. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the REST API below.

```
/_api/web/folders('Dinamico')/folders?$select=ListItemAllFields&$expand=ListItemAllFields
```